# How would you import settings from an exported drupal 7 omega 3.x?

Tags: 7, theming, importing-exporting

I'm able to export settings in omega via the export button: http://prntscr.com/29yr0r

I know I can download the theme, but I do not want that. I want to be able to copy and paste the code into my target omega sub theme. How would i import this to another sub theme for omega?